# Android player won't stop

Tags: java, android

I have call receiver , after first incoming  call , ringtone playing as usual , but after second or more incoming calls sound does not stop playing.

here call receiver :-

```
public class IncomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    /**
     * Processes the incoming call, answers it, and hands it over to the
     * WalkieTalkieActivity.
     *
     * @param context The context under which the receiver is running.
     * @param intent The intent being received.
     */

    WalkieTalkieActivity wtActivity;
    public SipAudioCall.Listener listener;
    public SipAudioCall incomingCall = null;
    public static Ringtone r;
    public int state = 0;


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        wtActivity = (WalkieTalkieActivity) context;
        try {
            incomingCall = wtActivity.manager.takeAudioCall(intent, listener);
            if (incomingCall.getState() == 3) {
                state = 1;
                Log.e("BUTTON", "Incoming Call here" + wtActivity.manager);
                wtActivity.updateStatus("INCOMING CALL " + incomingCall.getState());

                AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
                Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
                r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, uri);
                audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, maxVolume / 2, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
                r.play();
                wtActivity.setContentView(R.layout.incomig_call);


                Log.e("peer profile", incomingCall.getPeerProfile().toString());


            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (incomingCall != null) {
                incomingCall.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have static r , to stop r.play , on when call is end , but after calling again , I can hear two ringtones , and when I do end call , one ringtone stop play, but second continuous playing
I do not understand why please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone will have same issue . you need just unregister receiver after end call or on reject . this.unregisterReceiver(yourReceiver);